# Alternative of Code Switch and IF Else if else In Matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, switch-statement

Here is the MATLAB code first.  Below the code, I will discuss its problems, for which I need an alternative approach.

```
if((a>b) && (c>d) && (e==f) || (g<h) || (i==j))
msgbox('This is 1st','Recognize');
elseif((a>b) && (c>d) && (e==f) || (g>h) || (i~=j))
    msgbox('This is 2nd','Recognize');
elseif( (e==f) || (g<h) || (i==j))
    msgbox('This is 3rd','Recognize');
elseif((a>b) && (c>d) && (e==f))
    msgbox('This is 4th ','Recognize');
.
.
.
    elseif((a>b) && (c>d))
        msgbox('This is 32nd','Recognize');
else
msgbox('Condition not meet','Recognize');
```

**Problems I am facing:**

**1.** There are 32 different `if else if`. According to the rules, when one `if` or `elseif` becomes true, the rest will be skipped.

**2.** If I use only `if` (not `else`), then all will be checked individually, but it will take too much time for processing. And it may be that more than one condition becomes true at the same time.

**3.** `Switch` also works as `if else if`  (when a case is true, the rest are ignored).

The required solution is:  that **all 32 conditions should be checked** and the best will be executed.

Comment: I'd recommend to have a look into the principles of [**Karnaugh maps**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). I'm sure you could formulate your problem in such a way.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion. its difficult for me. well i will consider it as an option.

Comment: How do you decide the "best" of these 32 conditions?

Comment: Are you expecting several of these conditions to be `TRUE` at the same time? If so, do you want to execute all statements corresponding to a `TRUE` condition or only 1? If only 1, how do you decide which one has to be executed? (this rejoins @Divakar's question: how do you decide which is best?)

Comment: Why don't you give us more insight and explain **why** you need to check 32 conditions?  That way, we can possibly suggest alternative approaches to this (insufficient) scheme of performing tasks.

Comment: I have to check Urdu language Characters, user will input a Characters and press submit. and system will find its best match. if u know about Urdu. Urdu have many same words with litter difference. ب and پ are two Urdu language Characters  and between them only difference is dots. first has 1 dot and 2nd have 3 dots. So in this scenario I want all Characters  should be check and best will be executed. 
But Suppose user write پ (with three dots). and system because of 80% match understand it as ب (with one dot). and others will be ignored. then system gave wrong output. and it would be problem

Comment: Its a research project. and as i know research is never 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
action = 1^a + 2^b + 2^c + ...
```

and then use the number `action` for a `Switch` or to access a value in a cell or array (which contains your string).